# Text showing in preview of emulator but not in the device

Tags: android, textview

I've added a text and other views and on the Preview section they are shown as they should be but when I run the app on the emulator or on an actual device the text seem to be missing. I found the same problem with solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42189004/android-studio-textview-showing-on-preview-but-not-emulator-device) but did not solve my problem. I am going to attach photos below for more clarity.

[image: Image in preview]

[image: In Mobile Device]

I have tried as follows:

MyBoldTextView class

```
public class MyBoldTextView extends TextView {
public MyBoldTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    applyCustomFont(context);
}

public MyBoldTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    applyCustomFont(context);
}

public MyBoldTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int 
defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    applyCustomFont(context);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public MyBoldTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int 
defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    applyCustomFont(context);
}

private void applyCustomFont(Context context) {
    Typeface customFont = FontCache.getTypeface("fonts/ClanPro- 
NarrNews.otf", context);
    setTypeface(customFont);
}
```

}

MyBoldTextView implementation

```
  MyBoldTextView changePasswordTxt;
  changePasswordTxt = (MyBoldTextView) findViewById(R.id.changePasswordTxt);
```

My XML layout

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
android:orientation="vertical">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_15sdp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_15sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/corner_radius"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/_75sdp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/text_color_white"
            android:elevation="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:translationZ="@dimen/_4sdp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp">
                    <com.aayocab.app.Utils.MyBoldTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/first_name"
                        android:textColor="@color/black_text_color"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />


                    <com.aayocab.app.Utils.MyEditText
                        android:id="@+id/first_name"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                        android:inputType="textCapWords"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                        android:textColor="@color/black_text_color"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp">
                    <com.aayocab.app.Utils.MyBoldTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/last_name"
                        android:textColor="@color/black_text_color"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />
                    <com.aayocab.app.Utils.MyEditText
                        android:id="@+id/last_name"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                        android:inputType="text|textCapSentences"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                        android:textColor="@color/black_text_color"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/text_color_white"
            android:elevation="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:translationZ="@dimen/_4sdp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp">
                <com.aayocab.app.Utils.MyBoldTextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/phone_number"
                    android:textColor="@color/black_text_color"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
                <com.aayocab.app.Utils.MyEditText
                    android:id="@+id/mobile_no"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                    android:textColor="@color/black_text_color"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/text_color_white"
            android:elevation="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:translationZ="@dimen/_4sdp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <com.aayocab.app.Utils.MyBoldTextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/email"
                    android:textColor="@color/black_text_color"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
                <com.aayocab.app.Utils.MyEditText
                    android:id="@+id/email"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                    android:textColor="@color/black_text_color"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <com.aayocab.app.Utils.MyButton
            android:id="@+id/saveBTN"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/ripple"
            android:text="@string/save"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_18sdp" />
        <com.aayocab.app.Utils.MyBoldTextView
            android:id="@+id/changePasswordTxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_gravity="center" 
            android:text="@string/change_password"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
  <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_profile"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/login_title"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_15sdp"
    android:background="@drawable/circle_image"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_dummy_user" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

The text **Looking to change password?** is shown in preview but it is not shown in actual device

Comment: Could you show your MyBoldTextView class and all calls of setText after finding it by view's id? I think it relates to your logic

Comment: @ThinkTwiceCodeOnce I have edited my question..please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_15sdp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_15sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/corner_radius"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/_75sdp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
```

Just use `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` instead of `android:layout_height="match_parent"` hope it works fine